# Метка [core] - для чего?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core
У метки нет описания, синонимов. Для чего она создавалась и как предполагалось её использовать?

Comment: создавать метки может любой участник с 300+ репутации

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Думаю, ответ очевиден - метка бессмысленная, и создана была в результате ошибочной постановки меток [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) + [core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core) там, где должна была быть просто метка [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (так как "Java Core" означает просто стандартную библиотеку Java). Впоследствии, метку стали также лепить на вопросы по .NET Core, так что получилась полная каша.

Само понятие "Core" многозначно, и может кроме того относиться к:

- процессорному ядру
- семейству процессоров Intel Core
- дампу памяти в Linux (Core Dump)
- возможно, чему-то еще...

В связи с этим, сейчас эту метку нужно либо удалить, либо создать описание с указанием, какие метки нужно использовать вместо нее.

Comment: всё правильно. теперь, кто может удалять метки?

Comment: @Anatol Вручную - любой участник с >2000 репы, путем удаления ее из всех вопросов. Автоматом - разработчики могут запустить скрипт, если наши модеры их попросят.

Comment: странно, я думал есть возможность просто удалить метку, без каких-то там скриптов, не говоря уж об перелопачивании всех вопросов вручную.

Comment: @Anatol, ну вопросов всего 36, не так уж много. Но, правда, не факт, что после удаления ее со всех вопросов, кто-то не прилепит ее на свой новый вопрос и не создаст заново.

Comment: По идее лучше удалить (хоть вручную, хоть скриптом) и запретить создание.

Answer (score 4):

Во всех вопросах заменил метки на более релевантные, где разбираюсь, а где не разбираюсь — просто удалил метку.

UPD:

Большая часть вопросов была по .NET Core, где я разбираюсь и корректно заменил метки. По [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) вопросы были по базовой библиотеке, где эта метка не нужна. По остальным вопросам (их очень немного было) вообще не видел необходимости этой метки и они, в основном были очень старыми (ещё с хешкода).

Comment: *"а где не разбираюсь — просто удалил метку"* - надеюсь вы во многом разбираетесь, а то такой подход звучит так себе (на подлодке заменил все белые кабели на цветные, а где не разбираюсь - вырезал)

Comment: @Kromster Ну по .NET-тематике я заменил на более достойные метки, так что можете быть спокойны. В крайнем случае, можете просмотреть последние правки по моему профилю и попробовать улучшить ситуацию. Дело в том, что подобные мета-метки иногда можно вырезать без потери качества, тем более вопросов немного.